# mySQL query - grab users that are friends with user x

Tags: mysql

Say I have users and that users can be friends. I have a table of users and user data, and a table of friendships (connection id, user a id, user b id).

Is there a single query I could do in mySQL that would grab all of the users from the users table that are friends with user x? The fact that user x's id could be in either the a slot or the b slot in the friendships table makes this more complicated than I can figure out.

Edit For Clarity:

I need all of the data in the users table for friends of the current user. So I need the user data for user b if the current user is user a in the friendships table and vice versa. I want to end up with all of the data for all of the current user's friends (from the users table) based on the relationship in the friendship table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1729a/3) you can do:

```
SELECT u.name as friends
FROM friendship AS f
JOIN users AS u ON 
  ((u.user_id = f.user_a_id AND f.user_b_id = @user_id)
  or (u.user_id = f.user_b_id AND f.user_a_id = @user_id))
where u.user_id is not null;
```

In this `@user_id` is the id number of the user you want to find the friends for and the output are the names of the friends.

Comment: This didn't work for me because the left join caused it to return all friendships regardless of users and then the users that matched. When I changed the left join to a join it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. I will change it to a join for anyone looking at this in the future. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.user_id FROM users, friends WHERE (users.user_id=friends.user_a_id AND friends.user_b_id=x) OR (users.user_id=friends.user_b_id AND friends.user_a_id=x);
```